# Near maximum or minimum point, there are 2 points with the same value

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true to say that, for any real continuous function, if some point is maximum or minimum, then there exists a neighborhood of that point, and there must be 2 points with the same value in that neighborhood?

Comment: Presumably you would not allow the maximum or minimum point to be at an end point of the domain of the function.  Otherwise you could consider $f(x)=x$ with $x \in [0,1]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean continuous $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Let $x$ be a maximiser and pick points $a$ and $b$, in the interval around $x$, either side of $x$. Assume wlog $f(a) \le f(b)$. Then $f(b) \in [f(a),f(x)]$ as $f(x)$ is maximum, so by the intermediate value theorem there is a point $c \in [a,x]$ with $f(c) = f(b)$.

Then $c$ and $b$ are the points you're looking for.